# Why do I have to make an USB stick bootable if ISO image already is?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I've been searching with google for an easy understandable answer to my question and i didn't find one? Could someone explain this to me?
If i understand it, i will be happier

L.t: And why for the same image i just need to burn the image to a cd/dvd using a dvd-rom capable of writing for it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely with the tool you are using to write your ISO image to the USB stick.  This is hard to answer without knowing the tool you are using.

Best guess is that:

A - You may be writing the ISO image to a partition of the USB stick, instead of the entire device itself.  The bootsector of a disk or disk-like device is block 0, but partitions start much later.  (Since optical media doesn't have partitions the OS can't get in the way with them.)  Assuming Windows, try removing any drive letters or partitions on the device and applying the image again to ensure you are not selecting a partition.

B - Your tool that you are using to write the device may need some special setting to overwrite the bootsector or similar.

You may try using [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) to write the ISO file to "Partition0" of the device that's the USB stick.  This is an advanced low-level utility but will certainly work as long as the ISO is really bootable.

Be **extremely** careful with this utility - you should try to have no other <strike>USB devices</strike> USB storage devices connected when using this and double check to make sure you are telling `dd` to use the right drive.

(Try out the Win32diskimager suggested by @David Betz first before `dd`).

Comment: "... you should try to have no other USB devices connected ..." What about your keyboard and mouse? These day's there's no alternative to the USB keyboard and mouse. Just saying.

Comment: He meant no other writable usb storage device.

Comment: So let me tell you my context because maybe i didnt' express myself clearly. First scenario: Let'say i have an .iso file that contains xp sp3 which is by itself, a bootable image that i made it bootable again with power iso to a usb stick(a-data 16gb if it matters) to install windows from it, and it works, ok good nice one. Second scenario: the same .iso file but this time i burned using dvd-rom capable device using the same program(burn img to). The part that i don't get it is, why for the first scenario i have to make it bootable 2 times if the .iso already is. I hope you understand me now

Comment: Does the USB stick (before you make it bootable with power ISO) boot and then fail with an error, or is it not recognized as a bootable device at all?

Comment: a bit off topic tips: Use Rufus utility to create bootable flash drives from ISO. Or try even better tool Xboot to create flash drive with multiple ISOs with a boot menu!

Comment: It works either way

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not writing any boot information.

We have **zero** clue about your OS, so:

Linux (of=/X denotes path to usb):

```
dd if=myiso.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Windows:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/
```

There are other tools for Windows, but not all of them write all the required data (e.g. CentOS7, for example has special requirements which this tool satisfies).

Comment: i forgot to mention, windows xp

Comment: @udarH3 This should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but can you look to my comment above that i wrote to Lawrence? Tell me what you think if you have some time, thx